# Can i covert the R6 class object to dataframe and then export as csv ? by using R Package : openSkies

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I was planning to use the OpenSkies package to extract the Flight data and then export as a csv file, However i'm not able to convert the R6 class list as a dataframe, please advice me.

Thank you so much!!!

library(openSkies)
library(R6)

flights <- getAirportDepartures(airport="VHHH", startTime="2023-02-03 09:00:00",
endTime="2023-02-05 11:00:00", timeZone="Asia/Hong_Kong",maxQueryAttempts =1)

dataSet <- do.call(rbind, flights)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGEtI.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are `$field` in `R6` class, and you can extract them with `for` loop.

Double `loop`s are used, one for `length` of flights (there are 188 data in `flights`), and one for `fields` such as `origin_airport`.

```
require(openSkies)
require(R6)
flights <- getAirportDepartures(airport="VHHH", startTime="2023-02-03 09:00:00", endTime="2023-02-05 11:00:00", timeZone="Asia/Hong_Kong",maxQueryAttempts =1)

# You can choose what you want among the fields of flights.
target <- c('origin_airport', 'departure_time',
            'destination_airport', 'arrival_time',
            'call_sign','ICAO24')

# Assigning an empty list to store within data of flights
tempList <- list()

# Extracting data with loop
for(i in 1:length(flights)){
  for(j in target){
    if(is.null(flights[[i]][[j]])) {
      tempList[[j]] <-  c(tempList[[j]],NA_character_)
    } else{
      tempList[[j]] <- c(tempList[[j]], flights[[i]][[j]])
    }
  }
}

df <- data.frame(tempList)
```